# Помогите доделать переключатель света

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Мне нужно это зациклить (0n/off) и по кругу

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(function() {
    $('#img').click(function() {
      $('body').css('background', 'black');
      $('p').html('<p>off</p>');
      $('p').css('color', 'white');
      $('#img').replaceWith('<img id=im src="off.png">');

    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="off">
  <p>On</p>
  <div class="img">
    <img id="img" src="on.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам обязательно нужно применить jQuery и JavaScript или на СSS будет достаточно?

Comment: можно сделать с помощью toggleClass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('.switch').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('switch-off');
  $('body').toggleClass('body-off');
});
```

```css
.switch {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switch .off,
.switch-off .on {
  display: none;
}

.switch-off {
  background: red;
}

.switch-off .off {
  display: block;
}

.body-off {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switch">
  <span class="on">On</span>
  <span class="off">Off</span>
</div>
```